# Python output only lines who is not found in file b

Tags: python-2.7

I'm trying to make a script to get only the lines from file a that are not found in file b.

File a :

```
aaa
aba
atca
baf
```

File b :

```
aba
baf
```

Expected output:

```
aaa
atca
```

Comment: [Do you have any code from an initial attempt we could build on?](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's two main ways of doing this that I can think of:

### The memory-hungry way

```
with open("file_b") as fb:
    lines = fb.readlines()
# you may also want to remove whitespace characters like `\n` at the end of each line
lines = [x.strip() for x in lines]
with open("file_a") as fa:
    ifa = iter(fa)
    for line in ifa:
        sline = line.strip()
        if sline not in lines:
            print(sline)
```

Pros:

- Lower disk I/O due to only reading each file once

Cons:

- Higher memory requirements due to loading all of `file_b` at once

---

### The I/O-hungry way

```
with open("file_a") as fa:
    ifa = iter(fa)
    for linea in ifa:
        slinea = linea.strip()
        unique = True
        with open("file_b") as fb:
            ifb = iter(fb)
            for lineb in ifb:
                slineb = lineb.strip()
                if slineb == slinea:
                    unique = False
                    break
        if unique:
            print(slinea)
```

Pros:

- Low memory footprint

Cons:

- Reads all of `file_b` for every line in `file_a`

---

### Conclusion

I don't really know the parameters of what you're trying to do, so I don't know what (if anything) you need to optimize for. At work, I routinely process files many times larger than can fit in my workstation's memory, but I also know that disk I/O is much slower than memory access. So pick your poison. :)

Comment: If you turn `lines` into a set, the first approach reduces from `O(n^2)` to `O(n)` in time complexity.